# Multiplayer with Photon, but I am controlling the other character instead

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am using Photon PUN 2 for multiplayer in Unity.

I can create a room or join a room.

The problem appears when I join with a second player. When I control one of the players, I control the other player instead.

I am using Standard Assets FPS controller.

Do anyone know what is causing the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

I will share the edited code:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityStandardAssets.Utility;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using Photon.Pun;

#pragma warning disable 618, 649
namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (CharacterController))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof (AudioSource))]
    public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private bool m_IsWalking;
        [SerializeField] private float m_WalkSpeed;
        [SerializeField] private float m_RunSpeed;
        [SerializeField] [Range(0f, 1f)] private float m_RunstepLenghten;
        [SerializeField] private float m_JumpSpeed;
        [SerializeField] private float m_StickToGroundForce;
        [SerializeField] private float m_GravityMultiplier;
        [SerializeField] private MouseLook m_MouseLook;
        [SerializeField] private bool m_UseFovKick;
        [SerializeField] private FOVKick m_FovKick = new FOVKick();
        [SerializeField] private bool m_UseHeadBob;
        [SerializeField] private CurveControlledBob m_HeadBob = new CurveControlledBob();
        [SerializeField] private LerpControlledBob m_JumpBob = new LerpControlledBob();
        [SerializeField] private float m_StepInterval;
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip[] m_FootstepSounds;    // an array of footstep sounds that will be randomly selected from.
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip m_JumpSound;           // the sound played when character leaves the ground.
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip m_LandSound;           // the sound played when character touches back on ground.

        PhotonView view;

        private Camera m_Camera;
        private bool m_Jump;
        private float m_YRotation;
        private Vector2 m_Input;
        private Vector3 m_MoveDir = Vector3.zero;
        private CharacterController m_CharacterController;
        private CollisionFlags m_CollisionFlags;
        private bool m_PreviouslyGrounded;
        private Vector3 m_OriginalCameraPosition;
        private float m_StepCycle;
        private float m_NextStep;
        private bool m_Jumping;
        private AudioSource m_AudioSource;

        // Use this for initialization
        private void Start()
        {
            m_CharacterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            m_Camera = Camera.main;
            m_OriginalCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
            m_FovKick.Setup(m_Camera);
            m_HeadBob.Setup(m_Camera, m_StepInterval);
            m_StepCycle = 0f;
            m_NextStep = m_StepCycle/2f;
            m_Jumping = false;
            m_AudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            m_MouseLook.Init(transform , m_Camera.transform);

            view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        }


        // Update is called once per frame
        private void Update()
        {
           
            
                RotateView();
                // the jump state needs to read here to make sure it is not missed
                if (!m_Jump)
                {
                    m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
                }

                if (!m_PreviouslyGrounded && m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(m_JumpBob.DoBobCycle());
                    PlayLandingSound();
                    m_MoveDir.y = 0f;
                    m_Jumping = false;
                }
                if (!m_CharacterController.isGrounded && !m_Jumping && m_PreviouslyGrounded)
                {
                    m_MoveDir.y = 0f;
                }

                m_PreviouslyGrounded = m_CharacterController.isGrounded;
            

            
        }


        private void PlayLandingSound()
        {
            m_AudioSource.clip = m_LandSound;
            m_AudioSource.Play();
            m_NextStep = m_StepCycle + .5f;
        }


        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            if (view.IsMine)
            {
                float speed;
                GetInput(out speed);
                // always move along the camera forward as it is the direction that it being aimed at
                Vector3 desiredMove = transform.forward * m_Input.y + transform.right * m_Input.x;

                // get a normal for the surface that is being touched to move along it
                RaycastHit hitInfo;
                Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, m_CharacterController.radius, Vector3.down, out hitInfo,
                                   m_CharacterController.height / 2f, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);
                desiredMove = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(desiredMove, hitInfo.normal).normalized;

                m_MoveDir.x = desiredMove.x * speed;
                m_MoveDir.z = desiredMove.z * speed;


                if (m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
                {
                    m_MoveDir.y = -m_StickToGroundForce;

                    if (m_Jump)
                    {
                        m_MoveDir.y = m_JumpSpeed;
                        PlayJumpSound();
                        m_Jump = false;
                        m_Jumping = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    m_MoveDir += Physics.gravity * m_GravityMultiplier * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
                }
                m_CollisionFlags = m_CharacterController.Move(m_MoveDir * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

                ProgressStepCycle(speed);
                UpdateCameraPosition(speed);

                m_MouseLook.UpdateCursorLock();
            }

           
        }


        private void PlayJumpSound()
        {
            m_AudioSource.clip = m_JumpSound;
            m_AudioSource.Play();
        }


        private void ProgressStepCycle(float speed)
        {
            if (m_CharacterController.velocity.sqrMagnitude > 0 && (m_Input.x != 0 || m_Input.y != 0))
            {
                m_StepCycle += (m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude + (speed*(m_IsWalking ? 1f : m_RunstepLenghten)))*
                             Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            }

            if (!(m_StepCycle > m_NextStep))
            {
                return;
            }

            m_NextStep = m_StepCycle + m_StepInterval;

            PlayFootStepAudio();
        }


        private void PlayFootStepAudio()
        {
            if (!m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
            {
                return;
            }
            // pick & play a random footstep sound from the array,
            // excluding sound at index 0
            int n = Random.Range(1, m_FootstepSounds.Length);
            m_AudioSource.clip = m_FootstepSounds[n];
            m_AudioSource.PlayOneShot(m_AudioSource.clip);
            // move picked sound to index 0 so it's not picked next time
            m_FootstepSounds[n] = m_FootstepSounds[0];
            m_FootstepSounds[0] = m_AudioSource.clip;
        }


        private void UpdateCameraPosition(float speed)
        {
            if (view.IsMine)
            {
                Vector3 newCameraPosition;
                if (!m_UseHeadBob)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude > 0 && m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
                {
                    m_Camera.transform.localPosition =
                        m_HeadBob.DoHeadBob(m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude +
                                          (speed * (m_IsWalking ? 1f : m_RunstepLenghten)));
                    newCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
                    newCameraPosition.y = m_Camera.transform.localPosition.y - m_JumpBob.Offset();
                }
                else
                {
                    newCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
                    newCameraPosition.y = m_OriginalCameraPosition.y - m_JumpBob.Offset();
                }
                m_Camera.transform.localPosition = newCameraPosition;
            }
        }

          


        private void GetInput(out float speed)
        {
           

            // Read input
            float horizontal = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float vertical = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");

            bool waswalking = m_IsWalking;

#if !MOBILE_INPUT
            // On standalone builds, walk/run speed is modified by a key press.
            // keep track of whether or not the character is walking or running
            m_IsWalking = !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
#endif
            // set the desired speed to be walking or running
            speed = m_IsWalking ? m_WalkSpeed : m_RunSpeed;
            m_Input = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);

            // normalize input if it exceeds 1 in combined length:
            if (m_Input.sqrMagnitude > 1)
            {
                m_Input.Normalize();
            }

            // handle speed change to give an fov kick
            // only if the player is going to a run, is running and the fovkick is to be used
            if (m_IsWalking != waswalking && m_UseFovKick && m_CharacterController.velocity.sqrMagnitude > 0)
            {
                StopAllCoroutines();
                StartCoroutine(!m_IsWalking ? m_FovKick.FOVKickUp() : m_FovKick.FOVKickDown());
            }
        }


        private void RotateView()
        {
            if (view.IsMine)
            {
                m_MouseLook.LookRotation(transform, m_Camera.transform);
            }
            
        }


        private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
        {
            Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;
            //dont move the rigidbody if the character is on top of it
            if (m_CollisionFlags == CollisionFlags.Below)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (body == null || body.isKinematic)
            {
                return;
            }
            body.AddForceAtPosition(m_CharacterController.velocity*0.1f, hit.point, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to check if the view is yours, split the class inputs in his own class then each player will have to assign his own playercontroller to his "input manager"

Answer (score 0):

put isMine in your code and put the movement code inside of it

**Example:**

```
private void Update()
        {
         if(view.IsMine){ //Add this 
                RotateView();
                
                if (!m_Jump)
                {
                    m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
                }

                if (!m_PreviouslyGrounded && m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(m_JumpBob.DoBobCycle());
                    PlayLandingSound();
                    m_MoveDir.y = 0f;
                    m_Jumping = false;
                }
                if (!m_CharacterController.isGrounded && !m_Jumping && m_PreviouslyGrounded)
                {
                    m_MoveDir.y = 0f;
                }

                m_PreviouslyGrounded = m_CharacterController.isGrounded;
            
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this is that when a player joins its making a new "camera" so it changes changes the display. When I changed the Field of View on the cameras they changed to the correct player.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35531779)